# Concatenating Bitstrings in Elixir

Tags: elixir, binary-data

This piece of code throws error:

```
 iex(35)> a = <<18::size(7)>>
     <<18::size(7)>>
 iex(36)> b = <<100::size(7)>>
     <<100::size(7)>>
 iex(37)> <<a <> b>>
     ** (ArgumentError) argument error
```

Why this code fails?

How can I concatenate bitstrings using variables?

(I updated to example according to mudasobwa's remarks)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I concatenate bitstrings using variables?

#### If you have binaries, use [`Kernel.<>/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#%3C%3E/2):

```rb
iex|1 ▶ a = <<1, 2>>
#⇒ <<1, 2>>
iex|2 ▶ b = <<3, 4>>
#⇒ <<3, 4>>
iex|3 ▶ a <> b
#⇒ <<1, 2, 3, 4>>
```

It also works inside [`Kernel.SpecialForms.<<>>/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1):

```rb
iex|4 ▶ << a <> <<3, 4>> >>
#⇒ <<1, 2, 3, 4>>
```

Alternatively you might explicitly tell the compiler you use binary:

```rb
iex|5 ▶ << a :: binary, <<3, 4>> >>   
#⇒ <<1, 2, 3, 4>>
```

#### If you have bitstrings, the latter option works: use an explicit type hint:

```rb
iex|6 ▶ a = <<18::size(7)>>
iex|7 ▶ << a :: bitstring, <<100::size(7)>> >>
#⇒ <<37, 36::size(6)>>
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is to use a `bitstring` type hint:

```
iex(35)> a = <<18::size(7)>>
         <<18::size(7)>>
iex(36)> b = <<100::size(7)>>
         <<100::size(7)>>
iex(37)> <<a <> b>>
         ** (ArgumentError) argument error
iex(37)> <<a,  b>>
         ** (ArgumentError) argument error
iex(37)> <<a::bitstring,  b::bitstring>>
         <<37, 36::size(6)>>
```

Comment: Consider accepting the answer that helped you to solve this, rather than reiterating that answer.

Comment: Done. After editing, both question and answer look good. Thanks for moderation and removing inadequate comments.